# How to sort names in structures by last name? C++

Tags: sorting, visual-c++

So I am trying use bubble sort to sort names by last name. The names in question are stored in a structure and the structure is in an array. So how could I pull the name for each instance in for for loop and only organize by the last name?

```
struct Person{
string Name;
char Status;
double Income, Taxes, Net_Salary;
};




void B_sort(Person[], int size); //Prototype




Person  Plist[MAX_SIZE];// in int main()




void B_sort(Person Plist[], int size) // Here is the main course{
Person Temp;
bool Swap;
string first, last;

do{
Swap = false;
size--;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int blankpos = Plist[i].Name.find(" ");
    first = Plist[i].Name.substr(0, blankpos);
    last = Plist[i].Name.substr(first, blankpos); //not even sure if this is right, I really don't how to even
    if (Plist[i].Name > Plist[i + 1].Name){
        Temp = Plist[i];
        Plist[i] = Plist[i + 1];
        Plist[i + 1] = Temp;
        Swap = true;
    }
}
}while (Swap);
};
```

Comment: You should really be storing the first name and last name as two separate fields in the struct.

Comment: Indenting code inside {}-blocks is a good way to improve code readability. Your posting also could profit from proper indenting.